# Sorting collection of different models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm performing two queries:

```
@doodads= Doodad.all
@whatsits = Whatsit.all
```

I'm adding them to one collection:

```
@collection = @doodads + @whatsits
```

I want to sort them by their 'created_at fields:

```
@collection.sort_by $:created_at
```

While it does sort them by the created_at field, the item types are not intermingled - every Doodad comes first, followed by every Whatsit. How can I get this collected sorted properly?

Comment: Don't you have a typo there? Should be `&:created_at`.

Comment: We need a repro here, I think.

Comment: What kind of database you use there?

Comment: Do you mean that in the sorted collection objects are sorted first by type and then, within type, they are sorted by `created_at`?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Or not sorted at all because `@collection = ...` part is missing? Wild guess. @ArupRakshit might have guessed right, but his answer is wrong as it doesn't explain what happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do use [Array#sort_by!](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-sort_by-21):

> Sorts self in place using a set of keys generated by mapping the values in self through the given block.

```
@collection.sort_by! &:created_at
```

As you used `@collection.sort_by &:created_at`,where `sort_by` method works on the copy of the `@collection`,but that sorted one is not stored back to `@collection` again(i.e `@collection = @collection.sort_by &:created_at` will work also). Now the `sort_by!` does perform sorting on the receiver `@collection` itself.

Comment: Also, how does it answer the question?

Comment: I think so. Your answer doesn't answer the question.

Comment: I'll be happy to retract the downvote when the smoke clears. :)

Comment: This answered it perfectly. Total oversight on my part! The '!' operator performs the operation on the collection. In my original code, collection = collection.sort_by &:created_at would have worked, too. Thanks!

Comment: @TheSciz This didn't answer it, you did.

Comment: Collection was sorted properly, just not assigned. Saying "Do use `sort_by!` (because you forgot to assign the result)" doesn't look right to me.

Comment: @VictorMoroz NO... I said OP there is to way to solve this,- when you use `sort_by`,you need to store the result back using `=` operator,or do use bang method(`sort_by!`),which will do all job for you..You may read it wrong.